# Vscode showing white theme/text in my flutter dart code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, themes

[image: Error Image]

In the image above you can see that the whole dart code is showing white lines and this happened after my laptop accidently turned off while I was running the code.

The first error it gave was corrupted .git/packed-ref file which i fixed but this one isn't going away, other file type is showing their repective color theme only the .dart file is doing this. and also dart analyzer isn't working too

```
//Flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.0 at D:\flutter\Sdk\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cf44000065 (8 weeks ago), 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
    • Engine revision 40a99c5951
    • Dart version 2.15.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\bright\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0-rc2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\bright\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.34.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 97.0.1072.69

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I don't exactly know what the problem is, since it isn't showing me any error. Please what do i do?

Comment: try with reinstalling flutter and dart extensions

Comment: @YeasinSheikh already did still nothing, when i uninstalled it, the dart file began showing the theme color but when i reinstalled it again it went back to been white

Comment: You can check theme property:

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it isn't from theme property because dart analyzer isn't also working

Comment: could be, I am not sure about it. you can check [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73134)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the Dart extension (perhaps some files are corrupt), but uninstalling/re-installing it does not remove the files from disk and re-download it.

I would try uninstalling the Dart extension, then go into your `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions` folder and delete any `dart-code.dart-code` folders, and then re-launch VS Code and re-install it.

If that doesn't solve it, please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code. Thanks!

Comment: I also have this issue, but with Android Studio. I've opened up the `plugins` folder, but I don't see any of the folders you described. Do you have any ideas on how to resolve this?